# Binary search keeps adding a 1 on the end of the output

Tags: c++

I'm almost positive it's something simple, but i cannot for the life of me figure it out. This whole code is to print a menu which asks users for the and array size, then fills it with random numbers, sorts it ascending and descending, printing the array, as well as letting the user use a binary search or a sequential search. I know a linear search is much more efficient for what we're supposed to do, but the instructor insists on a binary search. I have the Binary search working, and it prints out the correct result, but with a 1 on the end of it(i.e position 14 comes out as 141). here's the switch case that calls the function:

```
case 7:
    int num, result;
    cout << "Please enter an int to search for" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    result = binarySearch(Array1, num, 0, size);
    cout << num << "was found at position " << result;
    break;
    }
}
```

here is the function:

```
int binarySearch(int arr[], int key, int first, int last)
{
    while (first <= last)
    {
        int mid = (last + first) / 2;
        if (key < arr[mid])
        {
            last = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (key > arr[mid])
        {
            first = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You don't do `cout << endl;` so the extra '1' is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Since 1 is printed irrespective of what you are searching for, it is very unlikely that the binary search logic has an issue. The binarySearch method is correct. Can you post what goes on after the switch condition ?

Comment: This is why you should try to make a concise test case before asking a question. You would discover the thing you think is the problem isn't the problem.

Comment: Agree with @Roddy, `1` comes from code outside `case 7:`.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried the code on my machine - I am not getting an extra  `1` appended to the output. So, I would think the `1` is being printed out somewhere else.

First, add in the space (or `endl` at the end of `cout`. This will confirm that the result you're getting is correct and also that the 1 is being printed elsewhere. Then, you can try looking for the extra 1 being printed in your code (after the switch() probably).

`cout << num << "was found at position " << result << " ";`

Update the rest of the code if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the whole reason was because i forgot to put that endl after result. After putting endl;. the 1 doesn't come up anymore.